# master detial page in xamarin android app

Tags: xamarin.android, master-detail

i'm trying to create an android app with a hamburger menu. I found out that I need to create a master detail page. so I added a master detail page to my layout but got an error: the type "MasterDetialPage" was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference...". 
I can't figure out what the problem is. I searched for a solution but didn't find one. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

MasterDetailPage exists in the Xamarin.Forms namespace so if you are creating a Xamarin.Android project you will not find it there and you will have to use Activities to achieve it.

Have a look at the documentation regarding MasterDetailPage https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page and also the one regarding Xamarin.Forms app creation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/first-app/?pivots=windows.

Comment: ah okay. so to get a hamburger menu in Xamarin.android I need something else. thank you very much

Comment: Yes. Have a look at this article https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-master-detail-view/

Comment: Please, if the answer was helpful, mark it as valid.